# Windows Forms C# TabControl ImageList Alignment?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, imagelist

Is it possible to align the image icon from on a TabControl's ImageList to the right of the text?

Right now, the image icon gets put on the left, and the text is to the right of that. I would prefer the text to be on the left, and the icon to the right of that. Is this possible?

Comment: You can set RightToLeftLayout = true, But this will also put the tabPages from right to left order.

Comment: Tinkering with the style flags had no effect.  You'll need to use the DrawMode property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that unless you Draw the TabPage yourself. To do that you need to set the `DrawMode` property of the `TabControl` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and then handle the `DrawItem` Event.

This is a very simple example to do that, you can add some code to change the background color of the selected tab if you wish, to know which tab is selected just check the `e.State` value:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // values
    TabControl tabCtrl = (TabControl)sender;
    Brush fontBrush = Brushes.Black;
    string title = tabCtrl.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    int indent = 3;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + indent, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - indent);

    // draw title
    e.Graphics.DrawString(title, tabCtrl.Font, fontBrush, rect, sf);

    // draw image if available
    if (tabCtrl.TabPages[e.Index].ImageIndex >= 0)
    {
        Image img = tabCtrl.ImageList.Images[tabCtrl.TabPages[e.Index].ImageIndex];
        float _x = (rect.X + rect.Width) - img.Width - indent;
        float _y = ((rect.Height - img.Height) / 2.0f) + rect.Y;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, _x, _y);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I handle the `DrawItem` event?

Comment: Select the TabControl, Then from the properties window click on the Events list (The lightning sign) then find DrawItem and click it twice. Or you can add `tabControl1.DrawItem +=new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);` in the Load event of the Form.

Comment: Hmm... okay, that worked... but using the above code, its pretty ugly. I want it to look exactly the same as the default tabs, just with the images on the right.