# TabControl with Big Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

My Windows Forms Applications project has a TabControl with Imagelist. What I need is square tabs with big Icons and Labels aligned Bottom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the ItemSize property to make them big.  Getting the text under the icon requires you setting the DrawMode property and painting the tab yourself with a DrawItem event handler.  Note that you can't use the TabPage.ImageIndex property, it will make the tab too wide.  Use, say, the Tag property instead.

Comment: Now I know DrawMode is better way to do this kind of article

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean you would like to change the tab "labels"

I don't think you can put the label underneath the image on a *TabControl* using just properties; but you could edit the images to contain the text. You can then remove the text from each *TabPage* to rely entirely on your images.

To make the tabs "square" set the *SizeMode* to *Fixed* and set your own size values (e.g. 42,42). You can then set the *ImageSize* to something similar (e.g. 40,40).

That should achieve what you are after, although you will have to update your images...

note: *ImageSize* property is a "subproperty" of the *Images* property of the *TabControl*.

note: As Hans Passant has said above, it seems you *can* put text under image by setting *DrawMode* and handling *DrawItem* - see this question: [Windows Forms C# TabControl ImageList Alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261436/windows-forms-c-sharp-tabcontrol-imagelist-alignment).

Comment: OP's requirements are not too clear (neither any overall-valid solution seems to be applicable). But, at least, you have made more effort to address what seem to be the OP's concerns. With just one answer is enough: delete mine and +1 for you.

Comment: @Nick and HansPassat thanx for suggestions, I had the exact solution.